# Menu on mobile don't disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery

On desktop my function works well on click appear and on another click disappear but on mobile on tap menu appear and on another tap disappear but immediately reappears why? thanks for the help

```
(function($) {
mobileMenu = function() {
    $('.btn-responsive-menu').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
        $("#menuleft").show();
        if ($("#menuleft").position().left == -17) {
            $("#menuleft").show().animate({
                left : "-400px"
            });
        } else {
            $("#menuleft").show().animate({
                left : "-17px"
            });
        }
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but I'd recommend you use CSS classes and the [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property instead of jQuery's `.animate()`, which might be heavy on some devices

Comment: @Matheus Avellar how use css?

Comment: Here's an example of using `transition` and changing menu's class name on click of the button: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9of606vr/). Hope it helps!

Comment: It is perfect thanks!

Comment: @Matheus Avellar but with jquery don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you should use css classes to do the animation.

```js
(function($) {
    $('.btn-responsive-menu').on('click', function(e) {
        var $menu =  $("#menuleft");
        var openClass = '-isOpen';     
        $menu.toggleClass(openClass, !$menu.hasClass(openClass));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#menuleft {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: .4s ease;
}

#menuleft.-isOpen {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.btn-responsive-menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-responsive-menu">toggle</button>
<div id="menuleft">
</div>
```